# Zero pivot during Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

If I encounter a zero pivot, and there is no non-zero candidate in any of the rows below it, can I make a *column* swap to select a replacement diagonal element?

The procedure I have implemented will reduce an ${N}\times{N}$ matrix to an ${(N-1)}\times{(N-1)}$ system to remove the problem pivot if a row exchange cannot be made. Then, once the system has be solved, I revisit any elements corresponding to deleted rows/columns and guess their values. This works, but for 4 unknown elements I only find that there are two valid solution vectors, and this leads me to believe that my procedure is not optimal.

Comment: If a row change cannot be made at some point, the matrix is singular and therefore the equation $Ax=b$ does not have a unique solution, but either infinite many or none.

Comment: I should mention it's a binary matrix with 0 and 1 entries only.